# Get a list of Transforms in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a list of Transforms for a spawn system. I have tried to use GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag with an array instead of a list and it seems like the array needs to be GameObjects and not Transforms, since that's what it's looking for. I've also tried another piece of code, but it only returns one random Transform into a list, here it is:

```
public List<Transform> t;

void Start()
{
    t.Add(GameObject.FindWithTag("Spawn").transform);
}
```

As you can see in my code, it will only add one Transform to my list. I would like to add multiple Transforms instead of just one.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Linq `Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) like

```c#
using System.Linq;

...

public List<Transform> t;

void Start()
{
    t = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Spawn").Select(go => go.transform).ToList();
}
```

This basically somewhat equals doing

```c#
var array = GameObject.FindObjectsWithTag("Spawn");
t = new List<Transform>(array.Length);
foreach(var go in array)
{
    t.Add(go.transform);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Array of gameObject:

```
GameObject[] gos;
gos = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Enemy");
```

To get the transform:

```
gos[0].transform
```

To make a list of transform:

```
public List<Transform> t;

foreach (GameObject go in gos)
{
   t.Add(go.transform);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to add these "spawn" objects to the list at the time of their creation instead of trying to find them afterwards. Is that an option?

For example:

```
GameObject spawn = Instantiate(spawnObj);
t.Add(spawn.transform);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public List<Transform> t;
public List<GameObject> go; //GameObjects where youl look for
 void Start()
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < go.Count; i++)
 {
    if (go[i].tag == "Spawn")
    {t.Add(go[i].transform);}
 }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.